# Regex, can't get it

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Seems easy but it doesn't work. I have something like this :

```
5224Reportage chez Ben ferme Ayrshire 2000 inc.2009-08-26T00:00:00-04:00En 2001, plutôt que de prendre le chemin de l’expansion, Ben ferme Ayrshire 2000 d’Hébertville au Lac-Saint-Jean a décidé d’ajouter le volet fromagerie à l’entreprise en misant sur la qualité.Revue/PLQ-2009-09/reportage.pdf5144Un deuxième Revue/PLQ-2014-07/production.pdf
```

From this I need an array containing :

```
Revue/PLQ-2009-09/reportage.pdf

Revue/PLQ-2014-07/production.pdf
```

I used :

```
$pdfResult = array(); 

preg_match_all('/^Revue.*pdf$/',$string, $pdfResult);
```

It returns nothing...

Comment: `^` and `$` mean match the start and end of the target string (or a line within that string).  Since you're looking for strings embedded within a larger string, I would start by removing those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy by default. You need to make it non-greedy by adding `?` quantifier next to `*`. And you don't need to put anchors, since the strings you want isn't at the start.

```
preg_match_all('~Revue.*?\.pdf~',$string, $pdfResult);
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7OY)